# Exception in c scanf_s

Tags: c, visual-studio, exception

I am trying to write a simple code to input values of an int and a char. Visual studio is throwing an exception

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {

    int i;
    char c;

    printf(" Enter the values");
    scanf_s("%c %d",&c,&i);

    return 0;
}
```

As i run the program and input values, visual studio is throwing an exception saying : Exception thrown at 0x599C939E (ucrtbased.dll) in main.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0032133E

Comment: @HansPassant — sizes are for character inputs, not for integers too.

Comment: @HansPassant, Jonathan Leffler: Maybe my comment isn't as spurious as some would suspect? I've **never** seen the `_s`-family of functions be used correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the sizeof memory you want to allocate for your char.

```
 scanf_s("%c %d",&c,1,&i);
```

Won't return any errors.
Since the scanf() function is kind of "unsafe", VS forces you to use the scanf_s function, which is a safer option.
This way, the user won't be able to trick the input.

Answer (score 1):

For format specifiers as `c and s` there is required to specify the size of the buffer after the corresponding pointer in the list of arguments.

In your case the function call will look like

```
scanf_s("%c %d",&c, 1, &i);
```

For format specifier `s` the size of the buffer also have to take into account the terminating zero.